# До електронних листів файли вкладені, приєднані чи прикріплені?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми, терміни, прикметники

Підтримка Microsoft очевидну перевагу надає **`вкладеним`** файлам:

[Вкладення файлів і вставлення зображень у повідомленнях електронної пошти Outlook](https://support.office.com/uk-ua/article/%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D1%96-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B8-outlook-bdfafef5-792a-42b1-9a7b-84512d7de7fc)

Як і підтримка Google:

[Як вкладати файли в листи Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=uk)

Водночас, досить поширені **`приєднаний`** файл та **`прикріплений`** файл.

Ось, до прикладу, підтримка ASUS використовує обидва з альтернативних:

[Email - Приєднати файл до листа](https://www.asus.com/ua-ua/support/FAQ/1011237/)

Пошук Google та й практика ділового листування рясніють варіаціями. Одного разу трапився навіть такий екзотичний як **`пристебнутий`** файл.

**Тож чи якийсь із трьох наведених варіантів вважається єдино правильним (може, це навіть термін), чи можна використовувати усі нарівні й це не буде помилкою?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Як Ви самі зазначили в запитанні, **однозначності немає**, але **більшість найвідоміших клієнтів наразі тяжіє до *вкласти/вкладення***.

Зокрема:

- Claws Mail — *долучення* (див. [файл укр. перекладів](https://git.claws-mail.org/?p=claws.git;a=blob;f=po/uk.po));
- Evolution — *долучення (див. [файл укр. перекладів](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GNOME/evolution/master/po/uk.po));*
- Geary — *долучення* (див. [файл укр. перекладів](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GNOME/evolution/master/po/uk.po));
- GMail — *вкладення*;
- KMail — *долучення* (див. [один із файлів перекладів](https://websvn.kde.org/*checkout*/trunk/l10n-kf5/uk/messages/pim/kmail.po));
- Mailspring — і *вкладення* / *вкладений файл*, і *прикріплення* (див. [файл укр. перекладів](https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring/blob/HEAD/app/lang/uk.json));
- Microsoft — *вкладення* (див. [Microsoft Terminology Collection і Translations in Localized Microsoft Products](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?searchTerm=attachment&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All+Products));
- Mozilla Thunderbird — *вкладення* (див. [один із файлів перекладів](https://hg.mozilla.org/l10n-central/uk/file/tip/mail/chrome/messenger/messengercompose/composeMsgs.properties#l307));
- [Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки) (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович, 2010)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=attachment&dicts=4&main_only=on&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) — *при́чіп*, *долу́чений файл*, *дода́ток*.

Втім, я не думаю, що якийсь із варіантів можна вважати «неправильним». Адже термінологія ще остаточно не сформувалася, а в загальному сенсі всі варіанти більш-менш передають потрібне значення.

Comment: Мені траплялося слово "прилога" в цьому значенні, від мовця. Що думаєте? Пошукала, в інеті знайшла лиш кілька згадок - у бібліографічному описі старої книжки XVIII ст. в значенні "додатку", в контексті релігійного термін, який я не зрозуміла, та в текстах по-болгарськи. Але "файл у прилозі" не дає мені спокою, так зручно вживати, на мій погляд. Як розібратися, чи воно підходить?

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, ну фактично, «правильно», по-моєму — це так, як більш-менш систематично вживають. _Прилогу_ в значенні «email attachment», НЯМС, вживають доволі рідко, але Ви можете спробувати створити традицію (якщо не боїтеся надто відрізнятися від інших), можливо, слово сподобається не лише Вам. Це слово справді є в словниках Уманця/Спілки та Кримського/Єфремова в значенні «додаток до документа/книги» (по-моєму, дуже підходяще значення для узагальнення в «дод. до листа»); але навіть у значенні «дод. до док./кн.» воно зараз рідко вживається; зате воно цілком інтуїтивно зрозуміле.

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, прорезюмую попередній комментар: (1) по-моєму, за значенням слово цілком підходить («додаток до документа/книги» добре переноситься на «email attachment»); (2) але наскільки я можу судити, зараз воно вкрай рідко вживається навіть в основному значенні («додаток до документа/книги»); (3) вирішувати Вам.

Comment: @Sasha, додам, що й в англійській теж співіснують *to attach/to enclose* та *attachment/enclosure*. Принаймні, в MS Outlook. (На роботі саме англ.)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, цікаво. А в яких там контекстах to enclose / enclosure? (Я надаю перевагу англомовному ПЗ, але Microsoft Outlook'ом ніколи не користувався, лише Outlook Express'ом (це інша програма, як не дивно) і дуже давно.)

Comment: @Sasha, наскільки я помітила, то *to attach/attachment* - коли приєднуються файли, *to enclose/enclosure* - коли, напр., в E-mail вкласти ще один (або ланцюжок) E-mail-ів. Може, ще є якісь відмінності, суто технічні або програмні, я не спец.